# Disable zooming on locate button press

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How can I disable zoom after the locate button (widget locate) has successfully found user location?

I am using esri JS (arcgis version 3.20).
I tried looking at docs but could not find answer whatsoever. 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_locate.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by setting scale to the map.scale value. :)

```
var scale = new www.scaleUtils.getScale($scope.map);
geoLocate = new www.LocateButton({
    map: $scope.map,
    useTracking: false,
    scale: scale             
}, "LocateButton");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
geoLocate = new LocateButton({
        map: map,
        setScale: false
    }, "LocateButton");

geoLocate.startup();
```